# mod_rewrite rule to redirect specific URL matches

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using mod_rewrite to redirect long URL's to specific pages. Its for a shop so basically if the URL is one folder deep it takes the user to a specific page, if the URL is two folders it takes them to another etc. I achieved this using the following...

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ shop.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ brand.php?category=$1&brand=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ handler.php?category=$1&brand=$2&product=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ handler.php?category=$1&brand=$2&product=$3&car=$4 [L]
```

Notice each rule is one folder deeper than the previous.

Rather than use another rule for the next stage which is the final product page I would rather take the user to http://www.domain.com/PRODUCT/DB/ID so I wrote a rule to check if the first folder was PRODUCT and if so take the user to PRODUCT.PHP?DB=$1&ID=$2...

```
RewriteRule ^product/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /product.php?db=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

It keeps returning a 404 error though. I placed this new rule just before the others in the hope it would execute this rule before any others (this appears to be 3 folders deep for which there is another rule when the first folder isn't PRODUCT)

The .htaccess and subsequent .php files are at the root level of the site.

Have I wrote the rule correctly? I have tried all sorts and looked everywhere but questions like this are generally related to ignoring a specific folder which I don't actually want to do.

Thanks

Comment: What are you doing with `\.` in the character class []? If you want to literally match a period/full stop, you don't need the escape. If you're trying to match everything between /'s, just use `[^/]+`.

Comment: I removed all the \. and nothing works with it like that?

Comment: Can you load `domain.com/product.php?db=db&id=123`?

Comment: `[^/.]+` (or \.) should match everything up to but not including the next / **or period**. One or more non-/ and non-. are required. That's why I asked if you really wanted to stop at a period. Are you saying that the first set of 4 RewriteRules work, but adding the 5th RewriteRule _before_ the other 4 gives a 404? product.php exists in the site root? You don't have any periods in your directory path names?

Comment: Yes the first 4 worked but the 5th (product) one didn't (I placed it before the other 4). Ive removed all of the back slashes and the original 4 work now but the /product one doesn't work. Yes it gives a 404 error. The .htaccess file and the product.php file are both located at the root (www.domain.com/product.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning off Multiviews:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Multiviews is part of mod_negotiation which tries to match a request to existing files, including ones that are missing the extension. So it's possible that mod_negotiation sees the request for `/product/something` and sees the file `/product.php` and serves up that file using PATH INFO, which will completely bypass mod_rewrite.

Comment: Yes that did the trick! Why does it fail to serve up the product.php file though? Its clearly doing what you said it might be doing but then gives a 404 error. Strange but thank you! It was driving me crazy!

Comment: @Scott Not sure, it could be several possibilities. Maybe your product.php file doesn't recognize the request and returns a 404 itself, or php isn't setup to do PATH INFO style requests